# Python FTP Error 550 when trying to upload file to server

Tags: python, file, ftp, server

Recently i have been getting this error in my python code, this is what is says: ftplib.error_perm: 550 temperatures.txt: Permission denied.

I am not sure what this means and how to fix it.

```
import serial
import time
import numpy
import ftplib
import os
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1',9600)
time.sleep(1)
ser.flush()


file = '/home/hazza/Desktop/test/temperatures.txt'
for i in range(2):

ser.readline()

while True:

temp  =((int(ser.readline())*0.004882814) - 0.5)*100
#print temp

f = open('temperatures.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(temp) + '\n')
f.close()

#upload file
s = ftplib.FTP('server','username','password')
print s.dir()
f = open('temperatures.txt','rb')
s.storbinary('STOR temperatures.txt' ,f)
f.close()
s.quit()
```

I had saved my textfile and my python file in a single file on the Desktop, does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is usually an error with the configuration of your FTP server, not an issue with the Python code. Are you sure you're storing your file in the right place and have given the appropriate permissions to your account on the FTP server?

Comment: Yes, i have stored both files in a single folder, and especially created a new account to log into, recieving no errors, i have look at similar problems to mine and i think it is about the permissions i have to the file, and when i check the directory of the ftp server, it is located at "/" i have tried changing the cwd to the file i am storing my python code in, but it keeps on giving me an error saying it does not exist, and i am not so sure how to fix that.